# Need to highlight the label when it is clicked in css or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to highlight the label, when it has been clicked. As same way it also needs to highlighted when we select the check-box. i resolve the check-box issue but unable to resolve the label click problem.

I solve the check-box issue by

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    background: #D7D5D5;
}
```

Reference code : http://jsfiddle.net/uU82C/

please help me to solve the label click problem in css, if not then in jquery.

Comment: If you are giving id='input-id' to input than assign the same value for the label attribute for='input-id'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 1) The "for" attribute in the label should be mapped to the "id" of the checkbox.
 2) The "id" contains space which is incorrect.
```

check the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/7KxUn/

I took the liberty to change the structure of your mydata

```
 var mydata =  { "fulldata":[
                  {
                        "child": {
                        "id":"c1",
                        "name": "child 1"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "child": {
                        "id":"c2",
                        "name": "child 2"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "child": {
                        "id":"c3",
                        "name": "child 3"
                        }
                    }
                    ]
                };
        return mydata;
    }
```

Mapped your id data to the checkbox and used for to map to this id.

Answer (score 2):

I would change handle the selection in "myclicktest" method and change the css a little bit like this.

```
label.selected,
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    background: #D7D5D5;
}

function myclicktest(event){
    var target = event.target;
    target.classList.toggle ("selected");
    if(target.classList.contains("selected")) {
        target.previousSibling.checked = "checked";
    }
    else {
        target.previousSibling.checked = "";
    }
}
```

**Note:**

I would suggest you not to use inline event registration like this

```
onclick='myclicktest(event)'
```

Its very bad idea, you should create elements dynamically and register the event handlers.

```
var inputEl = document.createElement("input");
inputEl.addEventListener("click", myclicktest);
```

Comment: @Hariharan You are welcome. I recommed you to create every thing dynamically that too with javascript. Once you know the internal working of javascript, you can shift to jQuery for faster develpoment.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).css({background: '#D7D5D5'});
    }
    else {
        $(this).css({background: '#FFF'});  // change this to whatever the background color normally is
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The id which was given to the child had spaces in string. Remove it and it will work. If you want your labels to check the `checkboxes`, you have to keep `for` attribute of `label` and `id` attribute of `input` type same.

Here is the updated jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/uU82C/12/

your code was very dirty!!